# npm install fails with apt-get update error -The following signatures were invalid: XYZ

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to upgrade npm:

```
npm install npm -g
```

Which seemed to show that I was installing the newest version. However, when I ran `npm -v` it still showed an older version. So I ran `which npm`, changed to that directory and ran:

```
 rm -rf npm
```

Now my npm installation is gone completely. How do I get it back? The npm install seems to only be a part of node, but I already have node version 9.11.2.

```
sudo apt-get update

W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1225425345345
```

I am unable to figure out how to fix this issue. I would like to restore my installation of npm version 6.4.1 and node version 9.11.2.

Comment: What is the problem with reinstalling node?

Comment: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs to perform these commands i get error - Err:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease                                       
  The following signatures were invalid: 6302C777E1A7FD81A2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing node and npm via n helped me come out of this issue.not bothering about package manager errors-

```
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm i -g n
sudo n 9
sudo npm i -g npm
```